# The space between the items in the Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    showSelectedLabels: false,
    showUnselectedLabels: false,
    items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: FaIcon(
          FontAwesomeIcons.solidCompass,
          color: darkblue,
        ),
        label: 'Home',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: FaIcon(
          FontAwesomeIcons.route,
          color: darkblue,
        ),
        label: 'Routes',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: FaIcon(
          FontAwesomeIcons.circlePlus,
          color: darkblue,
        ),
        label: 'Add',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: FaIcon(
          FontAwesomeIcons.solidMessage,
          color: darkblue,
        ),
        label: 'Chat',
      ),
    ],
```

[image]

I created such a BottomNavigationBar and added items to it, but the first item looks very separate from the others. How do I get the spacing between all items to be the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set "type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed," to set the same width on all the items. The space you see is on the selected index.

Like this:

```
BottomNavigationBar(
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    ...
)
```